# Code efficiency in calling methods of other class

Tags: java, memory, performance

I have three classes one is `Feature` and other `ContacstsSender` and `ContactsRetriever`. `Feature` class has two methods which are common in other both classes, they have to use them. These both methods contains a few lines of codes say 6 to 10. I want to know that is it ok to keep these classes and methods where they are or just put these small methods in both classes as calling from another class time and again could cost efficiency? And in concept of memory how would it be useful to call from a class and call method locally? Thanks

Comment: You might find this article I wrote interesting. http://vanillajava.blogspot.co.uk/2012/12/performance-of-inlined-virtual-method.html

Comment: I once had a relatively complex algorithm for processing events in a 2D tower defense game. I was certain that the game is running slow because of it. I tweaked it to the point of being incredibly unreadable and almost impossible to understand. Later on I finally decided to use a profiler. 80% of processing power was used in Math.atan2 calculation in a completely different place, and in a single place. By a simple tweak I reduced the processing time almost 5 times. TL;DR - use profiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> as calling from another class time and again could cost efficiency

What matters is not so much the location of the method as the location of the parameters used by the method in memory. But even the location of the parameters won't matter much in 99% of the situations.

> And in concept of memory how would it be useful?

Memory wise it makes no difference (apart from the size of the class files loaded by the class loader but we are talking in hundreds of bytes here).

So avoid code duplication and you'll be fine.

As usual with optimisation, the bottlenecks in your application are not where you think they are and you should use a profiler to find them.

Comment: +1 For pointing out you should profile before worrying about micro-optimisations.

Comment: what if I am using it for different platform say J2me where memory and these thing may matter a bit? Does that remain same or what?

Comment: @Saqib Compile your class with and without the method, check the difference of file size (the XXX.class file, not the source file) and decide if it is acceptable or not for your use case. You will probably conclude that the difference is minimal and your time would be better spent on other areas.

Answer (score 2):

Calling from the same class or another will, in general, cost the same [virtual method table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table) lookup.

I refer you to the wikipedia article for the full details, however the following quote explains Peter's comment quite well:

> Furthermore, in environments where JIT compilation is not in use, virtual function calls usually cannot be inlined. While a compiler could replace the lookup and indirect call with, for instance, a conditional execution of each inlined body, such optimizations are not common.
>   To avoid this overhead, compilers usually avoid using vtables whenever the call can be resolved at compile time.

An example of a way that the compiler will know to optimize away a vtable lookup include using the `final` modifier on either the class or the function (because then it is impossible for a subclass to override the functionality).

Comment: +1 This will only happens if the method cannot be inlined e.g. because there is more than 2 possible method which can be invoked.

Comment: Indeed, I deferred to the article originally but I decided to update it now to be more explicit about when a vtable lookup could be optimized out. (It's a bit late and I was being lazy...)